# Parsing arguments that are negative values using getopt - any way to make getopt ignore them?

Tags: bash, getopt, command-line-arguments

I'm using getopt to parse command line arguments for a script.
All optional arguments (-o and --long) are handled by getopt, but there are also mandatory arguments. Argument number 4 can be a path or a sequence of values which may be negative.

`script.sh mandatory/path/one mandatory/path/two mandatory/file.txt -200.12,32.7,-18.7`

If argument 4 begins with a negative value, the `-` will trigger getopt. Obviously, this breaks the script as getopt will complain about undefined options.

There are two workarounds that I can think of, but both are quite hacky:

1. do a sed on $@ to replace the `-` with some dummy string and then sed after getopt is done with the parsing to replace the dummy with `-` again.

```
ARGS=$(echo "$@" | sed -E "s/-([0-9])/%dummy%\1/g")
set -- "$ARGS"
ARGS=`getopt -o n -l no-act -n $0 -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$ARGS"
while :; do
  case "$1" in
    -n|--no-act)
      norun=1 ;;
    --) 
      shift; break ;;
    *)
      break 
  esac
  shift
done
ARGS=$(echo "$@" | sed -E "s/%dummy%([0-9])/-\1/g")
eval set -- "$ARGS"
```

2. define options with arguments in getopt -1234567890. This will split the mandatory argument 4 into `-2`and `00.12,32.7,-18.7`, which can be combined into an intermediate variable. In the end, the mandatory arguments 1-3 and 4 need to be `set` again.

```
ARGS=`getopt -o n1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:0: -l no-act -n $0 -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$ARGS"
while :; do
  case "$1" in
    -n|--no-act)
      norun=1 ;;
    -1|-2|-3|-4|-5|-6|-7|-8|-9|-0)
      TEMPVAR=$1$2
      shift ;;
    --) 
      shift; break ;;
    *)
      break 
  esac
  shift
done
```

There must be a more elegant way to do this. Getopt is doing a great job otherwise and I would like to keep it for the command line parsing.

(There are a few more options, I'm only mentioning the -n option in the example to keep the code block short)

EDIT: Mandatory argument 4 should stay $4, as there are further checks down the line.

Comment: To make getopt stop reading options, you can use the "--" trick : any option/parameter behind it is not taken by getopt

Comment: Can you give a code example? I've also checked the manual but am not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is - sort of. The problem here is that the `getopt` command doesn't really understand anything other than options that start with a hyphen, nor can you convince it to use anything other than a hyphen as the leader to an option. There isn't a way to tell getopt not to process an option in any other way.

However, `getopt` doesn't process *arguments*. It just passes that into the `$OPTARG` variable without any parsing whatsoever. So you have three options here:

1. If your options are positional, there's no reason to use `getopt` here. Just use `$1`, `$2` and `$3` as usual and fail the script on an incorrect count and/or an incorrectly-formatted number list. You can always count the number of arguments and treat the final one as your list, if you wish.
2. On the other hand, if your options are *not* positional, then you really should consider giving the numeric list its own option and then interpret `$OPTARG` specially.
3. Create your own option-parsing loop if what you're doing is very special. `getopt` is meant for relatively simple tasks, and there is such a thing as stretching its usefulness.

Any of the above would be commonly done in useful scripts. I encourage you to *not* complicate the issue, though. Scripts should be relatively simple, and Bash is best used as a command construction and dispatch language. We're not living in the days where Bash (or maybe just `sh`?) are the only languages available by default in the distribution. If you are trying to do some fairly complicated argument processing, you should strongly consider whether a general-purpose programming language like Perl, Python, or Ruby is a better choice for what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for your insights.
The mandatory arguments are positional (arg 1-4). However, there are 8 optional arguments. Those are handled by getopt and afterwards `$#` is 4. 

I agree that another language may have been a better choice here and a re-write in Python may happen at some point. When this script first came into existence, bash unfortunately was the only option for several reasons.

Comment: Fair enough. I've been there before myself, so I wasn't really judging your choice of language - just making a general statement there.

in your case, you probably want option #1 - just assign `$1` through `$4` to variables and then shift them out before you parse the rest via getopt. You really should not try to parse negative numbers via getopt if you can help it.

Comment: You're probably right. That will mean that all optional arguments have to be placed after the mandatory arguments. It would be nice to keep the freedom of placing options wherever, but it's not the end of the world if that is not possible anymore. The main issue is that the syntax slightly changes and users get confused.

Comment: I just realize that this may complicate things further...
There is a certain optional argument, that changes the behavior of the script. In that case, only one mandatory argument is required / allowed.

Comment: In that case, you might be better off having two separate option parsing loops, depending on that optional argument. Don't be afraid to repeat yourself a little in Bash. It's almost always best to be as uncomplicated as possible when writing shell scripts.